# DrawReversibleFrame foreground draw

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a PictureBox on my MainForm,

and if I try to DrawReversibleFrame, it will always draw the rectangular frame on the background behind the PictureBox

Is there a way I can draw the rectangle frame on the foreground?

DotNet 3.5
Windows 7 x64

Comment: some code please.... may be you are drawing on Form instead of PictureBox

Answer (score 0):

Add an OnPaint event for the PictureBox and use DrawReversibleFrame there.